# Connect Cloud Run Services to Compute Engine Mysql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, vpc

I trying to deploy my service on google cloud run.
Service is running well when i connect to cloud sql but considering the price i decide to use mysql that installed on google compute engine (VM).

When connect to cloud sql i using VPC Connector (Route all traffic through the VPC connector) to connect with cloudsql using private IP and there is no issue.
I only change DB_HOST from private cloudsql IP to private VM IP (installed with mysql).

env :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=PRIVATEIPCLOUDSQLORVM
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=MYDATABASE
DB_USERNAME=USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

There is no problem when my service that installed in VM still can connect to mysql(VM) also no firewall configured with 'block' state and im only using one vpc (default vpc).

Is there something missing from the configuration?

Comment: What is the problem? Are you trying to prevent local access to MySQL? In that case, use MySQL GRANT statements to control access. Please rewrite your post into a problem statement with details.

Comment: The problem is my service that deployed to cloud run can not connect to mysql that installed in compute engine.
No issue when connect to cloudsql, but cloudsql too expensive for me

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly state the problem. Include error messages when trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Give a bind address in mysql as 0.0.0.0 and also in env change `DB_PASSWORD=MYPASSWORD` to `DB_PASSWORD="MYPASSWORD"` using `""` due to current password include special.